# QSystemTrayIcon doesn't overwrite previous one on Linux

Tags: linux, qt, notifications

The program I'm working on has a feature to copy some data from server to client. So I use QSystemTrayIcon::showMessage function to show a notification popup.

Everything works fine on Windows and Mac. On Linux, specifically Ubuntu 14, the notification pops up one by one, with about 3 sec for each. Even when the second notification is shown right after the first one. On Windows and Mac, it would show the second notification and cancel the first one. But on Linux, the second notification has to wait until the first one time out.

So my question is is there any way I can make new notification overwrite the previous one?

My code is simply like:

```
QString title("foo");
QString detail("bar");
m_pTrayIcon->showMessage(title, detail);
```

Comment: Which desktop are you using?

Comment: @MrEricSir 
What do you mean by which desktop?

Comment: You know... KDE, Gnome, Fluxbox, etc. etc. They all handle tray icons very differently.

Comment: "So my question is is there any way I can make new notification overwrite the previous one?" - most probably there is none, if that is how the desktop environment handles messages. (that might be considered a good thing, so the first message doesn't get lost)